# 'FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

I've made an IOS build on Unity for an App we're making after adding the facebook SDK, moved the build on a hard drive and tried to build it on xcode on the mac we have at the office, as I always do before uploading it to the app store. I ran into this error and I've been stuck on this issue for 2 full work days and it's driving me a bit crazy, here are the thing's I've tried:

-Install cocoapods, both on the default terminal directory and on the project's directory (I'm not too experienced with cocoapods so I don't know if that made a difference. I also did pod update while standing on the project directory).

-I saw that the IOS resolver has an option called "generate pod files" that people said needed to be checked when building to solve this issue. It was checked by default on my project, so that wasn't it.

-Added the framework path on the build settings to where the facebook SDK is at (though the way it looked on my xcode seemed a bit different than the way I've seen it on other people's xcode screenshots)

-Tried commenting out some #include lines on the headers that are generating the issue. It only produced more errors.

-People said to open the project from the workspace instead of the xcodeproject but unity doesn't seem to generate a workspace file.

-Tried downgrading the Facebook SDK to a previous version but the versions people claim are working don't seem to be on the repository anymore, so it doesn't let me downgrade to them.

At the moment I'm trying to make it work with the latest Facebook SDK which is 9.0.0.

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if I'm not being specific enough about the issue or if there's any information about my project I should include on the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .xcworkspace should be created by Cocoapods, not by Unity directly.

If you already have the `Podfile` generated, just run `pod install` on the project directory and open the created .xcworkspace file after Cocoapods finishes installing the external dependencies.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so so much. I've no idea why I didn't run into these instructions somewhere on the web. Seriously thank you so much

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem as well, I think this is missing in Facebook's documentation.